# Extracting attributes out of the XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I want to extract attributes out of the xml file using this code
xml file is :

> ```
> xml= "<graphics type='xxx' port=’0’ autoport='xxx' listen='0.0.0.0'>
>   <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
> </graphics>"
> ```

and the code is :

> ```
> def xml_to_dict(xml):  
>       d={}   
>       if xmlk.text:
>          d[xmlk.tag] = xmlk.text  
>       else:
>          d[xmlk.tag] = {}   
>      children = xmlk.getchildren()   
>      if children:
>          d[xmlk.tag] = map(xml_to_dict, children)  
>          return d
>
>      xml_to_dict(xyz) Output: {'graphics': [{'listen': {}}]}
> ```

i have tried dmlk,attrib instead of tag but to no avail. Does anybody knows this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest lxml, but the following code works with either lxml or ElementTree

You also need to tweak your agorithm a bit:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

def xml_to_dict(tree):  
  d={}   
  if tree.text:
     d[tree.tag] = tree.text  
  elif len(tree) < 0:
     d[tree.tag] = {}   
  else:   
     d[tree.tag] = map(xml_to_dict, tree)  
 return d
```

That gives you what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree
dict(etree.fromstring(xml).items())
```

outputs

```
{'autoport': 'xxx', 'type': 'xxx', 'port': '0', 'listen': '0.0.0.0'}
```

Comment: or you can just use etree.fromstring(xml).attrib

Comment: i dont want to use lxml i have to use element tree...the code that i have posted what changes need to be made in that...thanks

Comment: this doesn't result in the data structure the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the output format you'd like to use. Here's one possibility that tries to be close to your code:

```py
empty = lambda s: not (s and s.strip())

def xml_to_dict(root):
    assert empty(root.tail), 'tail is not supported'
    d = root.attrib
    assert root.tag not in d, 'tag and attribute name conflict'
    if len(root) > 0: # has children
       assert empty(root.text), 'text and chilren conflict'
       d[root.tag] = map(xml_to_dict, root)
    elif not empty(root.text):
       d[root.tag] = root.text
    return d
```

It is not reversible in general case.

#### Example

```py
import pprint
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml = """<graphics type='xxx' port='0' autoport='xxx' listen='0.0.0.0'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
 <value>1</value>
 <blank/>
</graphics>
"""
pprint.pprint(xml_to_dict(etree.fromstring(xml)))
```

#### Output

```py
{'autoport': 'xxx',
 'graphics': [{'address': '0.0.0.0', 'type': 'address'}, {'value': '1'}, {}],
 'listen': '0.0.0.0',
 'port': '0',
 'type': 'xxx'}
```

Note: `<listen>` tag name is not present in the `graphics` list and `<blank/>` is reduced to `{}` in it.